# Как сохранить результат запроса к БД Interbase в скрипт файл.

Tags: скрипт, delphi, interbase, файлы

Есть компонент IBExtract, он позволяет извлекать метаданные БД (таблиц, процедур, триггеров...) в виде скрипта.
Вот пример кода который извлекает данные из таблицы **TABLE**

```
IBExtract.ExtractObject(eoData, 'TABLE');
IBExtract.Items.SaveToFile('d:\123.ddl');
```

Но мне нужно сохранять не все данные а определенную часть по условию.
Конечно можно выполнить запрос пробежаться по набору данных, сформировать скрипт и сохранить в файл.
Может есть еще какая нибудь возможность выгрузить данные по условию в скрипт?

Comment: Имхо, самый простой способ именно - выполнить запрос, пробежаться по результату и сформировать скрипт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас не смущает править исходники, то можно дописать процедуру ListData нужным вам образом. Или написать свою реализацию экспорта, примерно такую (сам не проверял, нет подходящей базы под рукой):

```
uses
   ... IB, IBDatabase, IBHeader, IBSQL, IBUtils
...
function MyListData(const Database: TIBDatabase; const ObjectName: string;
  const Filter: string = ''): string;
const
  SelectSQL = 'SELECT * FROM %s';  {do not localize}
  WhereClause = ' WHERE (%s)';     {do not localize}
var
  qrySelect: TIBSQL;
  FieldName, Fields, Values, DateStr: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  qrySelect := TIBSQL.Create(Database);
  try
    qrySelect.SQL.Text := Format(SelectSQL,
      [QuoteIdentifier(Database.SQLDialect, ObjectName)]);
    if Filter <> '' then
      qrySelect.SQL.Text := qrySelect.SQL.Text + Format(WhereClause,
      [QuoteIdentifier(Database.SQLDialect, Filter)]);
    qrySelect.ExecQuery;
    Fields := '';
    for i := 0 to qrySelect.Current.Count - 1 do
      if (qrySelect.Fields[i].SQLType <> SQL_ARRAY) and
         (qrySelect.Fields[i].SQLType <> SQL_BLOB) and
         (not Database.Has_COMPUTED_BLR(ObjectName, qrySelect.Fields[i].Name)) then
      begin
        FieldName := String(qrySelect.Fields[i].SQLVAR.sqlname);
        if Fields <> '' then
          Fields := Fields + ', '; {do not localize}
        Fields := Fields + QuoteIdentifier(Database.SQLDialect, FieldName);
      end;
    while not qrySelect.Eof do
    begin
      Result := 'INSERT INTO ' + QuoteIdentifier(Database.SQLDialect, ObjectName) + ' (';  {do not localize}

      Result := Result + Fields + ') VALUES (';  {do not localize}
      Values := '';
      for i := 0 to qrySelect.Current.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if (Values <> '') and (qrySelect.Fields[i].SQLType <> SQL_ARRAY) and
           (qrySelect.Fields[i].SQLType <> SQL_BLOB) then
          Values := Values + ', ';
        if qrySelect.Fields[i].IsNull and
           (qrySelect.Fields[i].SQLType <> SQL_ARRAY) and
           (qrySelect.Fields[i].SQLType <> SQL_BLOB) then
        begin
          Values := Values + 'NULL'; {do not localize}
        end
        else
        case qrySelect.Fields[i].SQLType of
          SQL_TEXT, SQL_VARYING :
            Values := Values + QuotedStr(qrySelect.Fields[i].AsTrimString);
          SQL_TYPE_DATE :
          begin
            DateTimeToString(DateStr, 'mm/dd/yyyy', qrySelect.Fields[i].AsDate);
            Values := Values + QuotedStr(DateStr);
          end;
          SQL_TYPE_TIME :
          begin
            DateTimeToString(DateStr, 'hh:mm:ssss', qrySelect.Fields[i].AsTime);
            Values := Values + QuotedStr(DateStr);
          end;
          SQL_TIMESTAMP :
          begin
            DateTimeToString(DateStr, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ssss', qrySelect.Fields[i].AsDateTime);
            Values := Values + QuotedStr(DateStr);
          end;
          SQL_SHORT, SQL_LONG, SQL_INT64,
          SQL_DOUBLE, SQL_FLOAT, SQL_D_FLOAT:
            Values := Values + qrySelect.Fields[i].AsTrimString;
          SQL_ARRAY, SQL_BLOB : ;
          else
            IBError(ibxeInvalidDataConversion, [nil]);
        end;
      end;
      Result := Result + Values + ')' + ';'#13#10;//Term;   {do not localize}
      qrySelect.Next;
    end;
  finally
    qrySelect.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Блин, была опечатка - исправил. Пример использования:<br>
Memo1.Text := MyListData(IBDataBase1, 'TABLE', 'Field3=48');

Comment: Спасибо за оказанную помощь, тоже уже пришел к такому выводу, просто не хотелось изобретать велосипед. Код ваш не проверял, перепишу стандартный из модуля IBExport под собственные, так сказать нужды.